# Query from database [Razor]

Tags: database, razor, menu

I have a problem with a query from database.

I have this table:

id | CatName | ParentIdCat

and I would like to create a list like this:

- Cat1
- Cat2 -> SubCat2a
- Cat3 -> SubCat3a -> SubCat3b -> ...

A kind of short menu
The number of subcategories is not fixed but variable.

I Use razor (not MVC).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to display the data when you don't know how many levels there are in the hierarchy. You can do this best by using a `helper` in Razor Web Pages. You select all of the data in one go, and then pass it to the helper which might look something like this:

```
@helper  BuildMenu(IEnumerable<dynamic> menu, int? parentid = null) {
    var items = menu.Where(m => m.ParentIdCat == parentid);
    var topLevel = true;
    if (items.Any()) {
        if(items.First().ParentIdCat.HasValue){
            topLevel = false;
        }
        foreach (var item in items) {
            if (!topLevel) 
            {
                @: ->
            }
            else
            {
                <br />
            }
            @item.CatName
            @BuildMenu(menu, item.Id)
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote an [article looking at using Recursion in Razor Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/208/Practical-Recursion-in-ASP.NET-Web-Pages-with-WebMatrix). It should provide some more background and assistance.